# get a list of objects with roles applied in be9 acl9

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, acl9

I think in something like this:

```
def self.obj_list(opts = {:include => [] , :exclude => []})
    # Returns an array with all objects with roles applied
    # +:exclude+:: (array,string) optional object type to exclude from list
    # +:include+:: (array,string) optional object type to include in list
    # Example:
    #   Role.obj_list(:include => ["Device", "User"])
    #   Role.obj_list(:exclude => ["User"])

    inc = opts[:include].to_a
    exc = opts[:exclude].to_a

    objs = []
    if inc.empty?

      self.all.each do |r|
        unless r.authorizable_type.nil?
          objs << r.authorizable_type.constantize.find(r.authorizable_id) unless exc.include?(r.authorizable_type)
        end
      end

    else

      self.all.each do |r|
        unless r.authorizable_type.nil?
          objs << r.authorizable_type.constantize.find(r.authorizable_id) if inc.include?(r.authorizable_type)
        end
      end

    end
    objs
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, maybe you want to link the object and subject?
If is this, here are a tutorial for that: https://github.com/be9/acl9/wiki/tutorial:-linking-object-and-subject-with-hmt

Answer (score 0):

You can use `where` clauses to do the include/exclude stuff in SQL:

```
( inc.empty?
? where.not( :authorizable_type => exc )
: where( :authorizable_type => inc )
).map(&:authorizable)
```

By using `authorizable` you will get Rails's own handling of polymorphic associations, which will ensure that only actual objects are returned, so there's no need to check for `nil`